# Which mail server is better heirloom-mailx or mailutils on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, sendmail

I am using AWS EC2 instance. I need to install a mail program on my EC2 instance. By default AWS is giving me two options :

```
heirloom-mailx
mailutils
```

Which one is better to use and why ? I will be running tomcat on this ec2 which would be sending emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly suggest you to think about sending mails via EC2 twice. In most cases it's not cheaper then using a external service & you have a lot of work ahead of you. Maintaining a mail server is not much fun …

*Things to consider, if you start using your EC2 instance as a mail server:*

1.) Register one or more Elastic IP addresses with AWS by filling out this form so that AWS can work to keep it white-listed with anti-SPAM agencies like spamhaus.org: https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request.

2.) Work yourself through this tutorial: http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/. It will help you to setup Postfix, which is a good choice for a mail server.

3.) Setup your DNS MX record correctly.